# Unexpected Token { in JSON parse

Tags: reactjs, json, function

I am trying to get a Postman Request for my Register Database, but get a 400 Bad Request.

The error in the console is saying:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 82
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parse (/Users/niloufarruthenberg/HappyRoutes/Backend/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:89:19)
```

and as well:

```
':' expected. [81,26]
',' expected. [81,42]
Property assignment expected. [82,7]
```

[Problems Description][1]

When I open the Json.js at the concerned place it shows:

```
/*!
 * body-parser
 * Copyright(c) 2014 Jonathan Ong
 * Copyright(c) 2014-2015 Douglas Christopher Wilson
 * MIT Licensed
 */

'use strict'

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 * @private
 */

var bytes = require('bytes')
var contentType = require('content-type')
var createError = require('http-errors')
var debug = require('debug')('body-parser:json')
var read = require('../read')
var typeis = require('type-is')

/**
 * Module exports.
 */

module.exports = json

/**
 * RegExp to match the first non-space in a string.
 *
 * Allowed whitespace is defined in RFC 7159:
 *
 *    ws = *(
 *            %x20 /              ; Space
 *            %x09 /              ; Horizontal tab
 *            %x0A /              ; Line feed or New line
 *            %x0D )              ; Carriage return
 */

var FIRST_CHAR_REGEXP = /^[\x20\x09\x0a\x0d]*(.)/ // eslint-disable-line no-control-regex

/**
 * Create a middleware to parse JSON bodies.
 *
 * @param {object} [options]
 * @return {function}
 * @public
 */

function json (options) 
  var opts = options || {}

  var limit = typeof opts.limit !== 'number'
    ? bytes.parse(opts.limit || '100kb')
    : opts.limit
  var inflate = opts.inflate !== false
  var reviver = opts.reviver
  var strict = opts.strict !== false
  var type = opts.type || 'application/json'
  var verify = opts.verify || false

  if (verify !== false && typeof verify !== 'function') {
    throw new TypeError('option verify must be function')
  }

  // create the appropriate type checking function
  var shouldParse = typeof type !== 'function'
    ? typeChecker(type)
    : type

  function parse (body) {
    if (body.length === 0) {
      // special-case empty json body, as it's a common client-side mistake
      // TODO: maybe make this configurable or part of "strict" option
      return {}
    }

    if (strict) {
      var first = firstchar(body)

      if (first !== {'{' && first !== '[')
      {
        debug('strict violation')
        throw createStrictSyntaxError(body, first)
      }
      }

    try {
      debug('parse json')
      return JSON.parse(body, reviver)
    } catch (e) {
      throw normalizeJsonSyntaxError(e, {
        message: e.message,
        stack: e.stack
      })
    }
  }

  return function jsonParser (req, res, next) {
    if (req._body) {
      debug('body already parsed')
      next()
      return
    }

    req.body = req.body || {}

    // skip requests without bodies
    if (!typeis.hasBody(req)) {
      debug('skip empty body')
      next()
      return
    }

    debug('content-type %j', req.headers['content-type'])

    // determine if request should be parsed
    if (!shouldParse(req)) {
      debug('skip parsing')
      next()
      return
    }

    // assert charset per RFC 7159 sec 8.1
    var charset = getCharset(req) || 'utf-8'
    if (charset.substr(0, 4) !== 'utf-') {
      debug('invalid charset')
      next(createError(415, 'unsupported charset "' + charset.toUpperCase() + '"', {
        charset: charset,
        type: 'charset.unsupported'
      }))
      return
    }

    // read
    read(req, res, next, parse, debug, {
      encoding: charset,
      inflate: inflate,
      limit: limit,
      verify: verify
    })
  }
}

/**
 * Create strict violation syntax error matching native error.
 *
 * @param {string} str
 * @param {string} char
 * @return {Error}
 * @private
 */

function createStrictSyntaxError (str, char) {
  var index = str.indexOf(char)
  var partial = str.substring(0, index) + '#'

  try {
    JSON.parse(partial); /* istanbul ignore next */ throw new SyntaxError('strict violation')
  } catch (e) {
    return normalizeJsonSyntaxError(e, {
      message: e.message.replace('#', char),
      stack: e.stack
    })
  }
}

/**
 * Get the first non-whitespace character in a string.
 *
 * @param {string} str
 * @return {function}
 * @private
 */

function firstchar (str) {
  return FIRST_CHAR_REGEXP.exec(str)[1]
}

/**
 * Get the charset of a request.
 *
 * @param {object} req
 * @api private
 */

function getCharset (req) {
  try {
    return (contentType.parse(req).parameters.charset || '').toLowerCase()
  } catch (e) {
    return undefined
  }
}

/**
 * Normalize a SyntaxError for JSON.parse.
 *
 * @param {SyntaxError} error
 * @param {object} obj
 * @return {SyntaxError}
 */

function normalizeJsonSyntaxError (error, obj) {
  var keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(error)

  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var key = keys[i]
    if (key !== 'stack' && key !== 'message') {
      delete error[key]
    }
  }

  // replace stack before message for Node.js 0.10 and below
  error.stack = obj.stack.replace(error.message, obj.message)
  error.message = obj.message

  return error
}

/**
 * Get the simple type checker.
 *
 * @param {string} type
 * @return {function}
 */

function typeChecker (type) {
  return function checkType (req) {
    return Boolean(typeis(req, type))
  }
}
```

This is the concerned code:

```
if (first !== {'{' && first !== '[')
      {
        debug('strict violation')
        throw createStrictSyntaxError(body, first)
      }
      }
```

I already tried to put the : and , but it didn'T change anything. And I don't know whats a property assignment.

Can anybody help and tell me how it would be correctly?

Manythanks!

Comment: You have to post Json at least, nobody needed your pictures.

Comment: You need to show the JSON that cannot be parsed, not the code that is trying to parse it. The obvious problem is that your JSON is either not at all JSON or somehow otherwise malformed and not meeting standards.